# Is this problem decideable programatically?

Tags: natural-language-processing

Consider the following 3 strings:

`1tb hdd 256gb ssd`
`hdd 256gb`
`1tb hdd`

If you know, that all of these strings are part of a product title, specifically part of the title of a Laptop product, a human can easily read these out, and understand that the specific laptop for which the respective string is part of has either hdd/ssd disk in it, and if it has, he can also decide the capacity of the said disk.

Is there any way to programatically make the same assumption **correctly**?

I am trying to parse the attributes of some products from their titles, and this exact problem arose: some titles have the ordering of `{disktype} {capacity}`, some have the ordering of `{capacity} {disktype}`, and I can't figure out a way to correctly identify the order, so that I can correctly parse the attribute and the data. In some cases, the titles contain `,` characters, which is very helpful in this situation, but there are a few cases where there are no other delimiters except `\s` characters.

To make things worse, some product titles only contain the following structure: `1tb ssd 512gb`. Based on the human understanding, and the context of the above string, for a human, it is still decidable which type of hard disk the laptop contains, and what capacity does it have, but can a computer do this programaticaly in a safe way also?

Comment: Is it straightforward what to do for products that have only a hdd or a ssd but not both?  If not, what are the difficult cases?  I see only one example, and it's not intuitive to me where that comes from (why would someone write that in a title? it seems ambiguous) or what the correct interpretation of it should be.  It might be useful to separate the case of "only hdd"/"only ssd" from handling products that have both a ssd and hdd.

Comment: @D.W. it is indeed ambigous, but those titles come from webshops around the world, and each to it's own - I am in no control unfortunately, on how they title their products. Basically, I can't say they are at fault in this at all, as I said it earlier, as a human, for me (with some basic knowledge of the topic) it easy to decide what is what in the title, and those titles were written for human consumption. Separation is a good preprocessing idea, which would help in some cases, but it still wouldn't solve the complete problem - however, I will definitely implement that as it will help

Comment: @D.W. however, separation will also fail on the example I have given in the last paragraph `1tb ssd 512gb` where the larger capacity is implied to be the hdd in the product - for that, my separation algorithm will imply that the product only contains `ssd` in it, and will still fail

Comment: Computers aren't magic.  If it's ambiguous, then ain't no algorithm gonna fix that.  I suggest you spend some time collecting examples of products that have only a hdd (or only a ssd) and where it is unambiguous for a human what the correct answer is and where a basic algorithm can't get the right answer.  Then, use that to see if there are some simple rules that can handle those cases, and [edit] the question to share your work and those examples.  That will help you figure out whether you can solve an important special case.  Basically, I am recommending you take a data-driven approach.

Comment: I know that they aren't:)) what I was asking for basically, if any one knows of an implementable solution, that I've missed (because of my limited logic for example), that could be used in this situation:) like your idea with separation, which would work in some cases, but would fail in others